# Реализация шорткодов в PHP

Tags: php

Как можно реализовать шорткоды (например, если ввести `{name}` то автоматически вставляется имя пользователя).

Может есть какие-то библиотеки или примеры? И как в целом это можно реализовать?

Comment: используйте шаблонизатор, например twig .

Comment: У вас все-таки сайт на WordPress, как я понимаю? И имя пользователя в WordPress? Если да, то "голым" php - никак, он ничего не знает про имя пользователя в WordPress.

Comment: @KAGG Design, нет сайт на голом PHP

Comment: Ну тогда лучше уберите из вопроса упоминание WordPress, потому что он только запутывает. Все равно на своем сайте вы не сможете применить функции WordPress

Comment: @ KAGG Design, убрал. Думал что все будут писать про WordPress т.к. в инете только по нему шорткоды нашел

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По разному. Самый простой вариант, если я вас правильно понял — [«Использование массивов с числовыми индексами в качестве аргументов функции preg_replace()»](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php#example-5420).

```php
<?php

$string = 'Hello, {name}. Welcome to {country}';

$patterns = [];
$patterns[0] = '/{name}/';
$patterns[1] = '/{country}/';

$replacements = [];
$replacements[0] = 'Nick';
$replacements[1] = 'Russia';

echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);

?>
```

https://eval.in/842803

Comment: Или вы хотите это делать на стороне клиента? Через JavaScript? Какой вопрос — такой и ответ)

Comment: А почему вы используете два отдельных массива для ключей и значений, вместо одного ассоциативного? Где ключи будут ключами, а значения значениями

Comment: @ Alexander Bragin, я не знаю. Главное чтобы работало) А если серьезно это нужно для шаблонов писем. Т.е. администратор может написать письмо пользователю при этом указать в письме только шорткод

Comment: @r.mcreal я так и подумал). В самых простых вариантах я делаю так как привел в ответе.

Comment: @ Alexander Bragin, вроде все работает, Спасибо!)

Comment: @r.mcreal, пожалуйста)

Comment: @Alexander Bragin, Еще такой вопрос, может вы знаете. Я смогу вставлять шорткоды в ckeditor(текстовый редактор)?

Comment: @r.mcreal вы имеете в виду, например, последовательность `{name}`? Я с `CKEditor` не работал, но наврядли он будет экранировать как-то `{` или `}`. То есть вы хотите шаблон редактировать в редакторе с возможностью его сохрананения? А почему бы и нет.